# Wordpress image upload from frontend throws 500 internal server error

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a site with a frontend form where users can add new post. The form has some basic post details and an featured image field. The form also has a few more image fields, which are controlled by acf.

Now the issue is when i use images like png everything works fine. But when i use images like jpg, it gives a internal server error. In acf i have added the accepted file formats as "jpg,png,jpeg". But i am not sure how to add file formats for the featured image.

Here is the code i am using. Here the first image will always be the featured image.

```
        foreach( $_FILES as $file ) {
            if( is_array( $file ) ) {
                if($count==1){
                    $featured_image_id = upload_user_file( $file );
                }else{
                    $item_image[] = upload_user_file( $file );

                }
            }
            $count++;
          }
```

And here is the upload_user_file function

```
function upload_user_file( $file = array() ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php' );
      $file_return = wp_handle_upload( $file, array('test_form' => false ) );
      if( isset( $file_return['error'] ) || isset( $file_return['upload_error_handler'] ) ) {
          return false;
      } else {
          $filename = $file_return['file'];
          $attachment = array(
              'post_mime_type' => $file_return['type'],
              'post_title' => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
              'post_content' => '',
              'post_status' => 'inherit',
              'guid' => $file_return['url']
          );
          $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file_return['url'] );
          require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
          $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $filename );
          wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $attachment_data );
          if( 0 < intval( $attachment_id ) ) {
            return $attachment_id;
          }
      }
      return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i solved it. For some reason the allowed file types in acf didn't work for me. So i just removed the types (ie allow all file types) and everything came back to life. I know this might not be suitable for everyone, but i guess this points you in the right direction of where the issue might be.

Comment: Hey, can you elaborate on this? I'm pretty sure I'm experiencing the exact same issue as you.

Comment: There is an option inside the image field called "allow file types". This is what the documentation says "Add upload validation for specific file types. Enter a comma seperated list to specify which file types are allowed or leave blank for all types. Added in v5.1.9". So if you leave it empty it will allow all file types. In some rare occasions  wordpress htaccess file is not updated, so try going to settings > Permalinks and click on save. This will update your htaccess file.